# Count number of Saturdays between two dates - MySql

Tags: mysql, date

I am attempting to view two columns from my table, ***received_on*** and ***closed_on***.  I also wanted a third column that counted how many saturdays existed between the two dates in each row.

So far, I was thinking something like

```
where year(date)=2011 and weekday(date)=5
```

So my question again is ***how can I count how many Saturdays exist between two dates in each row?***

**EDIT**

Row 1:

```
received_on 2013-11-29 closed_on 2013-12-02
```

## of Saturday's: 1

Row 2:

```
received_on 2013-12-4 closed_on 2013-12-09
```

## of Saturday's: 1

Comment: your where clause would return rows only where the `date` is a saturday in 2011. It wouldn't return a friday, or a monday or any other non-saturday.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, any suggestions on how I would be able to count the number of Saturday's then?

Comment: quick/dirty: determine how many weeks are between the two days, which gives you a rough saturday count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT received_on,closed_on, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(received_on), DATE(closed_on))/7) as numofsat FROM table
```

Comment: I tried doing this SELECT count(*) FROM `calls`
WHERE
received_on = received_on and closed_on = closed_on
GROUP BY WEEK(closed_on) and it obviously gave me some crazy #'s.  I'm taking it I'm not on the right track?

Comment: Why do you use WHERE received_on = received_on since you search for a specific date?

Comment: No, the dates I'm using are the dates received_on and created_on equal in each row.

Comment: @CBC_NS It will return the number of weeks between columns for each row.You can remove the DATE keyword if the columns are DATE type.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm almost back at square one.  I'm not trying to find the number of weeks.  I simply want the number of Saturdays.  See edit to OP in a moment.